# How to download the pictures produced by OpenAI through the returned URL?

Tags: openai-api, httpsurlconnection

I have tried a lot of methods, but any OpenAI produced picture URL will time out?
Even if using HttpsURLConnection, setting connection timeout and read timeout doesn't work?
METHOD1:
`FileUtils.copyURLToFile(source, destination, connectionTimeout, readTimeout);`

METHOD2:
**code：**

[image: 1]

ERROR：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGo5H.png)

ERROR：
Connect to oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net:443 [oaidalleapiprodscus.blob.core.windows.net/20.150.70.100] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

Answer (score 0):

The response URL of the API maybe is not support blob.
You can try by using response_format = "b64_json".
Example code:

```
function base64ToFile(b64Data, filename, contentType) {
  const sliceSize = 512;
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
  const file = new File([blob], filename, { type: contentType });
  return file;
}

export async function createImageByDescription(
  description,
  numberImgs = 2,
  size = "1024x1024",
  response_format = "b64_json"
) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations",
      {
        prompt: description,
        n: numberImgs,
        size,
        response_format,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer {token}`,
        },
      }
    );

    const imageFiles = await Promise.all(
      response.data.data.map(async (item, index) => {
        const file = await base64ToFile(
          item.b64_json,
          `image${index}.png`,
          "image/png"
        );
        return file;
      })
    );

    return imageFiles;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error createImageByDescription:", error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: `The response URL of the API maybe is not support blob.` Can you provide a reference to support this argument? The code example seems good otherwise.

Comment: I have some tests with DALL·E preview app. You can try to click to download button, the URL for download like is: `blob:https://labs.openai.com/398c9649-ef2d-4a2a-bc2e-0045cf15ff0d`